# Wordpress or Apache or Nginx matching partial URL to full URI

Tags: wordpress, apache, 301-redirect, url-rewriting, nginx

I have a weird issue where either Nginx or Apache (I can't tell which - but I'm 90% sure it's Apache - Nginx is reverse proxying) is matching a partial URL to a full, random URL.

For example: https://example.com/php

Is being rewritten/redirected to: https://example.com/php-full-article-url

But as far as I'm aware, I don't have anything in my config's that would result in this behaviour!

Nginx conf:

```
server { 
    server_name example.com; 

    root /var/www/html/examplecom/; 
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    set $skip_cache 0;
    set $skip_reason "";
    proxy_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri;

    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author_|wordpress_(?!test_cookie)|wp-postpass_" ) {
            set $skip_cache 1;
            set $skip_reason Cookie; 
    }

    if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
        set $skip_reason URI; 
    }
    add_header Cache-BYPASS-Reason  $skip_reason;


    location / {
        try_files                   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        proxy_buffering             off;
        proxy_cache                 edge-cache;
        proxy_cache_revalidate      on;
        proxy_cache_use_stale       error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_cache_bypass          $skip_cache;
        proxy_no_cache              $skip_cache;
        proxy_cache_valid           200 301 302 500m;
        proxy_cache_valid           404 1m;
        add_header X-Cache-Status   $upstream_cache_status;
        #add_header X-Handled-By    $proxy_host;
        add_header                  Cache-BYPASS-Reason     $skip_reason;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header            Host $host;
        proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass                  http://127.0.0.1:8080$request_uri;
        add_header                  Front-End-Https on;
        proxy_redirect              off;
        proxy_buffering             off;
        proxy_cache                 edge-cache;
        proxy_cache_revalidate      on;
        proxy_cache_use_stale       error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_cache_bypass          $skip_cache;
        proxy_no_cache              $skip_cache;
        proxy_cache_valid           200 301 302 500m;
        proxy_cache_valid           404 1m;
        add_header X-Cache-Status   $upstream_cache_status;
        #add_header X-Handled-By    $proxy_host;
        add_header                  Cache-BYPASS-Reason     $skip_reason;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    #listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    #include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    #ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
    ssl_ciphers TLS13-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:TLS13-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS13-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        allow all;
    }
    location ~* .(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires                     max;
        log_not_found               off;
        proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header            Host $host;
        proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect              off;
        proxy_buffering             off;
        proxy_cache                 edge-cache;
        proxy_cache_revalidate      on;
        proxy_cache_use_stale       error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_cache_bypass          $skip_cache;
        proxy_no_cache              $skip_cache;
        proxy_cache_valid           200 301 302 500m;
        proxy_cache_valid           404 1m;
        add_header                  X-Cache-Status  $upstream_cache_status;
        add_header                  Cache-BYPASS-Reason     $skip_reason;
        proxy_pass                  http://127.0.0.1:8080$request_uri;
    }
}
server {

    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri; 
    }

    if ($host = dev.example.com) {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri; 
    }

    # managed by Certbot

    listen   80;

    server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    #ServerName example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/examplecom/

    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    Header unset ETag
    FileETag None

    CacheQuickHandler off

    #CacheRoot               /var/cache/apache2/mod_cache_disk
    #CacheEnable            disk /
    #CacheDirLevels             2
    #CacheDirLength             1
    #CacheMaxFileSize        2000000

    #CacheIgnoreNoLastMod    On
    #CacheDefaultExpire      7200
    #CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
    #CacheLastModifiedFactor 0.5
    CacheIgnoreHeaders      Set-Cookie Cookie
    #CacheHeader            on

    #CacheLock              on

    CacheDisable            /wp-admin
    CacheDisable            /wp-login.php
    CacheDisable            /wp-cron.php

    #SetOutputFilter        CACHE

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    </FilesMatch>

</VirtualHost>
```

Wordpress .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN W3TC CDN
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
# END W3TC CDN

# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType text/css .css
    AddType text/x-component .htc
    AddType application/x-javascript .js
    AddType application/javascript .js2
    AddType text/javascript .js3
    AddType text/x-js .js4
    AddType text/html .html .htm
    AddType text/richtext .rtf .rtx
    AddType image/svg+xml .svg
    AddType text/plain .txt
    AddType text/xsd .xsd
    AddType text/xsl .xsl
    AddType text/xml .xml
    AddType video/asf .asf .asx .wax .wmv .wmx
    AddType video/avi .avi
    AddType image/bmp .bmp
    AddType application/java .class
    AddType video/divx .divx
    AddType application/msword .doc .docx
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
    AddType application/x-msdownload .exe
    AddType image/gif .gif
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .gzip
    AddType image/x-icon .ico
    AddType image/jpeg .jpg .jpeg .jpe
    AddType image/webp .webp
    AddType application/json .json
    AddType application/vnd.ms-access .mdb
    AddType audio/midi .mid .midi
    AddType video/quicktime .mov .qt
    AddType audio/mpeg .mp3 .m4a
    AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
    AddType video/mpeg .mpeg .mpg .mpe
    AddType video/webm .webm
    AddType application/vnd.ms-project .mpp
    AddType application/x-font-otf .otf
    AddType application/vnd.ms-opentype ._otf
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database .odb
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart .odc
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula .odf
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics .odg
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation .odp
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet .ods
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text .odt
    AddType audio/ogg .ogg
    AddType application/pdf .pdf
    AddType image/png .png
    AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint .pot .pps .ppt .pptx
    AddType audio/x-realaudio .ra .ram
    AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
    AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf
    AddType application/x-tar .tar
    AddType image/tiff .tif .tiff
    AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf .ttc
    AddType application/vnd.ms-opentype ._ttf
    AddType audio/wav .wav
    AddType audio/wma .wma
    AddType application/vnd.ms-write .wri
    AddType application/font-woff .woff
    AddType application/font-woff2 .woff2
    AddType application/vnd.ms-excel .xla .xls .xlsx .xlt .xlw
    AddType application/zip .zip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/x-component A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/x-js A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/html A3600
    ExpiresByType text/richtext A3600
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A3600
    ExpiresByType text/plain A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xsd A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xsl A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xml A3600
    ExpiresByType video/asf A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/avi A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/bmp A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/java A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/divx A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/msword A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-msdownload A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/gif A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/webp A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/json A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-access A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/midi A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/quicktime A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/mpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/webm A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-project A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/pdf A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/png A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/x-realaudio A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-tar A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/tiff A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/wav A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/wma A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-write A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/zip A31536000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_brotli.c>
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType BROTLI_COMPRESS text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/bmp application/java application/msword application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-msdownload image/x-icon image/webp application/json application/vnd.ms-access video/webm application/vnd.ms-project application/x-font-otf application/vnd.ms-opentype application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text audio/ogg application/pdf application/vnd.ms-powerpoint image/svg+xml application/x-shockwave-flash image/tiff application/x-font-ttf application/vnd.ms-opentype audio/wav application/vnd.ms-write application/font-woff application/font-woff2 application/vnd.ms-excel
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # BROTLI_COMPRESS by extension
        AddOutputFilter BROTLI_COMPRESS js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/bmp application/java application/msword application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-msdownload image/x-icon image/webp application/json application/vnd.ms-access video/webm application/vnd.ms-project application/x-font-otf application/vnd.ms-opentype application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text audio/ogg application/pdf application/vnd.ms-powerpoint image/svg+xml application/x-shockwave-flash image/tiff application/x-font-ttf application/vnd.ms-opentype audio/wav application/vnd.ms-write application/font-woff application/font-woff2 application/vnd.ms-excel
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|htc|less|js|js2|js3|js4|CSS|HTC|LESS|JS|JS2|JS3|JS4)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         Header unset Set-Cookie
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|HTML|HTM|RTF|RTX|SVG|TXT|XSD|XSL|XML)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|webp|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|webm|mpp|otf|_otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|_ttf|wav|wma|wri|woff|woff2|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip|ASF|ASX|WAX|WMV|WMX|AVI|BMP|CLASS|DIVX|DOC|DOCX|EOT|EXE|GIF|GZ|GZIP|ICO|JPG|JPEG|JPE|WEBP|JSON|MDB|MID|MIDI|MOV|QT|MP3|M4A|MP4|M4V|MPEG|MPG|MPE|WEBM|MPP|OTF|_OTF|ODB|ODC|ODF|ODG|ODP|ODS|ODT|OGG|PDF|PNG|POT|PPS|PPT|PPTX|RA|RAM|SVG|SVGZ|SWF|TAR|TIF|TIFF|TTF|TTC|_TTF|WAV|WMA|WRI|WOFF|WOFF2|XLA|XLS|XLSX|XLT|XLW|ZIP)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         Header unset Set-Cookie
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(bmp|class|doc|docx|eot|exe|ico|webp|json|mdb|webm|mpp|otf|_otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|svg|svgz|swf|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|_ttf|wav|wri|woff|woff2|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|BMP|CLASS|DOC|DOCX|EOT|EXE|ICO|WEBP|JSON|MDB|WEBM|MPP|OTF|_OTF|ODB|ODC|ODF|ODG|ODP|ODS|ODT|OGG|PDF|POT|PPS|PPT|PPTX|SVG|SVGZ|SWF|TIF|TIFF|TTF|TTC|_TTF|WAV|WRI|WOFF|WOFF2|XLA|XLS|XLSX|XLT|XLW)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         Header unset Last-Modified
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade"
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache

# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} br
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_br]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.xml%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.xml%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any help here would be GREATLY appreciated. https://example.com/php should not be rewriting to https://example.com/php-full-article-url - because it's not a legitimate match/binding/whatever it's called.

I have just checked my Apache access logs: `127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2019:14:42:14 +0000] "GET /php HTTP/1.0" 301` - so it is doing a 301 redirect within Apache!!! I just don't know why

I've cleared Nginx caching, restarted both Apache and Nginx (and PHP for good measure).

Happy to give some real world example url's if that helps? I have a set of posts that all start `/review-` however if I just visit `/review` (expecting to get a 404 error - which is exactly correct!), it seems to just pick a random post and redirects/rewrites to serve that up instead (`200 OK`!)

*Note: Originally asked on SO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54809631/) but got no responses - I feel it's probably more appropriate here*

Comment: You have a "front controller" rewrite rule for WordPress:  `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`  This assigns every URL that isn't an actual file or directory to be handled by WordPress.  It is WordPress itself that is doing this, not your config files.

Comment: Thanks @StephenOstermiller - is this standard wordpress behaviour? I'd never noticed this before, but it seems... "dangerous" to me to _"match"_ part of a url to a full resource. For instance, I have a lot of posts that start `/review-`, but if I just visit http://example.com/review - I get one random post. If these were products (let's say `/blue` where I have `/blue-tshirt`, `/blue-trousers` & `/blue-jumper`), how does WP decide which page to use? Surely in that scenario, if there are multiple matches it should just be forwarding to http://example.com/?s=blue *not* picking a single page??

Comment: The front controller is standard WordPress stuff (almost all content management systems do it.)   I know that WordPress has some settings for how your URLs should look, but I'm not well versed in them.   Ideally it would show a 404 error or redirect for URLs that aren't in exactly the right format.  I'm not sure if there are plugins that would help make that happen.

Comment: Thanks @StephenOstermiller - do you want to pop that in as an answer and I'll accept it? :)

Answer (score 1):

Per @StephenOstermiller's comments - this is actually something WordPress is handling (albeit, not very well).

It's basically guessing the full URI by picking a post/page that happens to have the same word in it!

I asked the question on WP's support forum and as it turns out, fortunately, there's a very easy way to disable this behaviour. One of the forum mod's gave me the following resource: https://www.bloggersignal.com/stop-wordpress-from-guessing-urls/

TL;DR - if you want to retain maximum SEO friendliness, pop the following in your `functions.php`

```
function wmse_121146_no_redirect_404($redirect_url)
{
    if ( is_404() ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $redirect_url;
}
add_filter('redirect_canonical', 'wmse_121146_no_redirect_404');
```

See WordPress forum question: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-front-controller-redirecting-partial-urls